# Customizing UIBarButton makes it too big

Tags: ios, ipad, button, customization

So when I try to set a custom color to a UIBarButton, it causes the displayed button to be too big and it extends down past the NavigationBar and into the main view of the app. Is there an easy way to fix this? Here is my code:

```
UIImage *buttonColor = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue-background.jpg"]
                     resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5)];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:buttonColor forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                      barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 0):

try playing with the values of the `UIEdgeInsetsMake` function.
in one of my apps it looks like this;

```
UIImage *backbuttonimage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"backbutton.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 15, 0, 10)];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:backbuttonimage
                                                              forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

it made it as i wanted... if you have any problems i would like you to tell me and if you can add a photo of how it looks for me to understand better the problem.

these are my values for my app:

```
UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 15, 0, 10)
```

have a nice day :)

Comment: So I tried doing that and it definitely allows me to change the size a bit but there seems to be an absolute minimum size that is still too big :/

Comment: have you made two files? one for the retina display and one of the regular display? (iphone 3g for example)
**it needs to be like:**
`image.png`
**and the retina version:**
`image@2x.png`

and the size of the `@2x` is double than the regular photo.

this could also be the problem you are having.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i make custom `UIBarButtonItem` and it works perfect for me. Try this:

```
UIButton *postView = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 61, 30)];
[postView setTitle:@"Post" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[postView addTarget:self action:@selector(showAddPost) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[postView setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bbi_texture.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[postView setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bbi_texture.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

UIBarButtonItem *postButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:postView];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:postButton];
```